# IOS 10 Losing Connection when Device is locked

Tags: ios, webrtc, ios10, hybrid-mobile-app

Im developing a mobile hybrid app to work on Android and iOS, using webRTC to make/receive calls. Im using cordova-iosrtc plugin for iOS. Everything was working fine on iOS 9.3, I could make and receive calls on the background and when the device was locked the connection was still running. With the update of iOS 10 I loose the Websocket connection when I press the lock button, but the app runs fine on the background, just when I lock the device in the physical button it losses the connection.

Any idea what it might me ? Tried using cordova-backgroundmode but still isnt working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only use background sockets if you are developing a VOIP app. Apple restricts background running for apps to save battery life. Only audio, location updates, VOIP, accessory apps are allowed to run in the background. In some modes you can only responds to changes (location based, remote notification & background fetch).

Comment: Thanks for you response, the thing is I have correct behaviour on the background (if I press the Home button), only when I physically press the lock device button on the Iphone / iPad it losses the connection. Only happens on iOS 10.

Comment: How did you get the background running support in working in iOS 9? It could be that Apple changed the way it works in iOS 10, this does not mean that you can get around the background restriction just because on iOS 9 you could.

Comment: I Dont have nothing thats specifies the background state in iOS 9 , I just have it enable in xcode with the Voip configuration. I just want to keep the websocket alive when I lock the device because it seems to loose it as soon as it locks the device. Im trying this plugin now: katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode